# A GPS based application DESIGN

Tags: android, locationlistener

my dilemma is about how to design an application which have the following features:

1. camera preview. (must be on the ui thread)
2. heavy image processing on request (thought maybe on a remote service with AIDL and even thought to make it with asyncTask in order not to hold the ui)
3. location listener which updates globals (in the application layer)

I really don't know if it is wise to have the main activity to implement a LocationListener - wouldn't it be bad for the ui? is there any other way to achieve that?

10x.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how listening to location updates in an activity can be bad for UI.

Bad for UI are heavyweight processes on the UI thread because when UI thread doesn't respond for more than some seconds Android shows Application Not Responding dialog.

But in case of listening to location updates this doesn't happen on the UI thread even if you make your activity the listener.

Comment: i want to minimize a s much as possible any lag in the ui, and that is why im thinking about taking everything outside the ui thread..